# How can I change the paper size for Qt QPrinter?

Tags: qt

I'm trying to print PDFs with Qt and it's working fine. However, in certain cases I'd like to change the size of the paper AFTER I know how much will really be printed.

I'm trying to change the paper size of the device attached to my `QPainter` object, but it doesn't impact the actual output.

Here's what I'm doing in pseudo code:

```
printer = new QPrinter(...);
printer->setPaperSize(...); /* eg. A4 */

painter = new QPainter();
painter->begin(printer);

determine_page_size_by_trial_rendering(frame, printer, *painter);

printer->setPaperSize(....); /* eg. A5 */

real_rendering(frame, printer, *painter)
```

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to get this going. I feel like the `QPainter` object somehow keeps the page size somewhere and I'm not able to reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - i figured it out already believe it or not. I had been looking for more than a day, but it turned out to be simple - i just destroyed the Painter objected and then opened a new one:

```
painter->end();
painter = new QPainter(printer);
```

That solved it...